# I am getting infinite loop in java output

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Actually I tried implementing the code for a Problem in hackerrank where we need to find diagonals difference and give absolute of it. But when I try to print the output outside of loop it says unreachable code. And if I use it inside the for loop I am getting infinite loop.

```
import java.util.*;
public class HourGlass  
{
    public static void hour(int k)
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n,sum1,sum2,sum3,i=0,j=0;
        n=sc.nextInt();
        int a[][]=new int[n][n];
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                a[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<=n-1;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<=n-1;j++)
            {
                i=0;
                j=0;
                {
                    sum1=a[i][j]+a[i+1][j+1]+a[i+2][j+2];
                    sum2=a[i+2][j]+a[i+1][j+1]+a[i][j+2];
                    sum3=sum1-sum2;
                    k =Math.abs(sum3);
                }
                System.out.println(k);  
            }
        }
    }
    public static void  main(String args[]){
        HourGlass h=new HourGlass();
        h.hour(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your setting `i = 0; and j = 0;` inside your loop...it will never exit.

Comment: You are initializing i and j inside the second for loop. So i and j will be reinitialized and you will end up in infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen that you're modifying the loop variables inside the loop ?

Remove

```
i=0;
j=0;
```

And the loop will end.

Comment: The problem is I need to add these because I need to initialize a array as i=0,j=0 and I need to traverse through the position above to get the output.If I delete it then it throws arrayindexoutofbound exception

Answer (score 3):

```
for(j=0;j<=n-1;j++)
{
    i=0; // this line needs to go away. its resetting the counter.
    j=0; // this line needs to go away. its resetting the counter.

}
```

Remove the two lines as commented above. Every time the loop runs it sets `i` and `j` to 0.

Answer (score 0):

But if I remove the 2 lines it throws arrayindexoutofboundException.
I want to explain my logic.Actually I need to initialize an array as to 0 and traverse the two index values i and j to respected positions as mentioned in code.Please help